# Sort-able images with overlapping transparent borders, and handle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of images which have large areas of transparency (margins) around them. I'm trying to use them in a "sortable" but this makes dragging the correct image troublesome as they all overlap and their margins cause the wrong image to be dragged.

Unfortunately the transparent areas can't be cropped out.

So I tried to create a thin "handle" bar across the center of each image, but the handle isn't dragging the image at all.

```
$(".item").sortable({
    handle: ".handle"
});
```

[**Here is a JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/BkUvD/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the sortable function, you have to appy it to a "surrounding container" like a `<ul>` or a `<div>`.

So all you need to do to make your fiddle work is to surround your three divs with another div eg. `<div id="srt"> <div>... </div>`

In your jQuery call you need to adjust it like this:

```
$("#srt").sortable({
    handle: ".handle"
});
```

Check out the corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BkUvD/16/